# Can I use a .vdi file in a virtual box for Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Is it possible to use the Windows XP that I installed in a virtual box in Windows.
To be used in Ubuntu 9.10 Virtual box? So that I won't install the whole thing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can mount and use .VDI files in any VM inside VirtualBox (but to use it as a VM inside another VBox you will need to setup the VM itself again)
2. You can export the existing VM in your Windows XP and import it under Ubuntu (have a look inside the File-menu).